# Console window still popping up even after ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Tags: c#, process, console-application, invisible

I have to run a console application from my Windows Application. The console application I want to run is an Embedded Resource in my application, and I am calling it like this:

```
// Run the updater and grab its output
Process Updater = new Process();
Updater.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\tmp\\tmp.exe";
Updater.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Updater.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Updater.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Updater.Start();
string UpdaterOutput = Updater.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Updater.WaitForExit();
```

It extracts fine, and it runs fine, and it also grabs its output completely fine... but I can still see the console Window popping open quickly as it's run. I know the console pop up is from this application because the console title is `C:\tmp\tmp.exe`. Is there any completely fail proof way to hide the console application? I thought using `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` would do it but apparently not.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is answered, please close your thread.

Comment: @Hans Passant - Can my answer be accepted if I have hit the rep cap for the day?

Comment: @fletch: sure, no cap on answer mark points.

Comment: @Hans: I hate when people do this.

Comment: And I hate when people jump to conclutions. I had to wait another 5 minutes or so before I accepted an answer. I was tired and I went to bed. Rest assured that the answer is now accepted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the [ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx) property to `true`

Comment: Ah, I had used that before but didn't think it made a difference when I used `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`. And I needed to set it to true, not false.

Thanks very much! :)

Comment: is that as well or instead of?