# Execute cmd without prompt in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, cmd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Console window still popping up even after ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497924/console-window-still-popping-up-even-after-processwindowstyle-hidden)

I'm developing an application which creates junctions, which is a native ability of cmd.exe (it is a cmd function, it isn't a separate exe), the command is "mklink /J Link Target". Quite simple.

But the application will be doing 50 or so in a row, and I really don't want 50 prompts to come up, it would be very annoying.

My code currently looks like this:

```
Public Sub createJunction(ByVal link, ByVal target)
    Dim shortcutexec As New Process()
    Dim arguments As String = "/Q /C mklink /J """ + link + """ """ + target + """"
    shortcutexec.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    shortcutexec.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments
    shortcutexec.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    shortcutexec.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    shortcutexec.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

    shortcutexec.Start()

    'Debug
    MessageBox.Show(shortcutexec.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd())
End Sub
```

Although I'm redirection output, setting window style to hidden, the prompts are still coming up. **Is there another way of doing this, without have the prompts appearing?**

Thanks!

Comment: It is, thanks for that, i missed it

Comment: You may wish to use an approach that does not require calling cmd.exe.  See this link:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15633/Manipulating-NTFS-Junction-Points-in-NET  It uses a pinvoke call to DeviceIoControl.