# Trigger a PS1 file from C# code. C# code has to be wrapped in exe

Tags: c#, powershell, exe

I have a powershell script which I want to trigger from an EXE.

Things already tried or cannot do:

- Can't run powershell directly because process running it is expecting an exe and not a powershell.
- Powershell script is pretty complex, so porting it to C# will not be trivial and will be very time consuming.
- PS2EXE works, but cannot use because of security policy.
- Tried to google on how to create an exe for a ps1 file, but couldn't find any solution (except ps2exe). So I decide to try to execute ps1 using C# and then create an exe. Then wrap both exe and powershell in same msi.

Tried by simply creating Process and starting it:

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell.exe");
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-Executionpolicy unrestricted C:\script\ms.ps1";
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        p.Start();
```

Above code is working, however it is flashing a black cmd windows for a millisecond or so.

Tried following code from source: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C

```
        string scriptText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\script\ms.ps1");
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

        pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

        pipeline.Invoke();
        runspace.Close();
```

Same problem as above, flashing a black windows for few seconds.

Answer to any of following questions can solve my problem?

1. How can I create an exe for powershell without using PS2EXE?
2. How can I disable windows popup when invoking powershell from C# code?
3. Is there any other way I can solve my problem?

--
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the [CreateNoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497924/console-window-still-popping-up-even-after-processwindowstyle-hidden)?

Comment: Add -windowstyle hidden to your arguments when invoking PowerShell.

Comment: What kind of security policy allows one to run a home-brewn C# applications, but not Ps2Exe applications?

Comment: So is the only problem that it flashes a window?

Answer (score 0):

> Hello! You can select "Windows Application" in the project properties instead
>   of the console
>   [image]
>
> Maybe it help you for this: /flashing a black cmd windows/
>
> Also you can run commands whithout running the script (something like
>   this):

```
string MyCommand = "-Command &{ if (!(Test-Path 'c:\\test')) {md 'c:\\test'; get-process | Out-File c:\\test\\MyFile.txt}}";

            ProcessStartInfo MyProcInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();


            MyProcInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
            MyProcInfo.Arguments = MyCommand;

            Process MyProcess = new Process();
            MyProcess.StartInfo = MyProcInfo;
            MyProcess.Start();
            MyProcess.WaitForExit();
```